# Opencart Related Product Interaction

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

While adding product A, we can add products B, C, D to related products. In the system, it automatically adds product A in product B itself. Here I want to remove this interaction. How can i do it? I use opencart 3.0.3.8 version

Comment: By default Admin cannot do this. A module is required.